# Button Clicks in Fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments, button, onclicklistener

I am using fragments and I want to register a button click, but I'm getting this error when I try to use android:onClick.

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find method preferenceChange(View) in a parent or ancestor Context for android:onClick attribute defined on view class android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton with id 'btnSave'
```

I tried looking at different solutions but nothing has worked. I am not running Lolipop.

Comment: where did you do the btnSave function ?

Comment: In a fragment called PreferencesView.java

Comment: Can you post your full fragment and activity code?

Answer (score 1):

if you're using the

```
android:onClick
```

you need to invoke the method in the activity not the fragment , if you want to do on click in a fragment you can always use this example

```
final Button button = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.button_id);
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
public void onClick(View v) {
    // Perform action on click
}});
```

Comment: I am using tabs and my MainActivity doesn't create the fragments but another java class does but it isn't an activity. Where should I put it?

Comment: in a setonclicklistener i would say

Answer (score 1):

What I did to fix the problem was make the activity implement the View.onClick Listener:

```
implements View.OnClickListener
```

Then in the Activity Created Method set the onClick Listener:

```
@Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        btnSave = (Button) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.btnSave);
        btnSave.setOnClickListener(this);
    }
```

Then implemented the methods that I needed to implement:

```
@Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()) {
            case R.id.btnSave:
                preferenceChange();
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }

    }
```